# Move controls of Colorbox into node

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) (v.  7.x-2.8) and [Colorbox Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) (v.  7.x-3.5) to display some nodes in a Colorbox. I would like to move the controls (previous, next, etc) into the node that is displayed in the Colorbox. I have created (by using a DS code field) a `div` with id `cboxControls`. So the following piece of jQuery should make it:

```
$('#cboxPrevious').prependTo('#cboxControls');
//And so on for the other controls.
```

The prroblem is, where should I place the code? My first attempt were to put it in the .js of my Colorbox style, that is here:

```
Drupal.behaviors.initColorboxPlainStyle = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $(context).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
      //Put the code here?
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

This doesn't work, since the `cbox_complete` seems to fire before the HTML of the node is put into the page - there is no `cboxControls` yet.

So where can I put the code instead? Or can I solve this in some other way?